# SQLite Transaction fails with .NET

Tags: vb.net, sqlite, transactions

i am trying to implement SQLite in our backed and run into a problem that i get timeout and exception that database is locked in this simple code

```
try
  lDb.ConnectionString = String.Format("Data Source={0};Version=3;Pooling=True;Max Pool Size=100;", TextBoxSqlite.Text)
  ldb.Connection = New SQLiteConnection(ldb.ConnectionString)
  ldb.Connection.Open()
  lDb.Connection.BeginTransaction()

  for lIndex As Integer = 1 To 100
    lQuery = String.Format("INSERT INTO [TableTest] VALUES ('{0}','{1}','{2}') ", lIndex , lIndex , lIndex )

    lCommand = New SQLiteCommand()
    lCommand.CommandText = lQuery
    lCommand.Connection = lDb.Connection
    lDb.ExecuteCommand(lCommand)
  next

   ' if ok'
   db.CommitTransaction()
catch ex as exception
  ' if failed rollback'
  db.RollbackTransaction()
end try
```

It runs once, on second run it hangs couple of seconds and throw exception.
The first insert ist not (rightfully) inserted.

if i remove the BeginTransaction line it works as advertised.

I use the .NET SQlite (System.Data.SQLite) in latest 3.12 version

Any idea what it might be?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is this really the actual code you're using? What are `lDb` and `db`?

Comment: sorry it was in huger function, i tried to copy paste / adapt the important parts what removed some readability. db is SqLiteConnection and ldb is our wrapper class using it.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k2hy99x.aspx) says:

> Follow these steps to perform a transaction.
>
> 1. Call the BeginTransaction method of the SqlConnection object to mark the start of the transaction.
> 2. […]
> 3. Execute the required commands.
> 4. Call the Commit method of the SqlTransaction object to complete the transaction, or call the Rollback method to end the transaction.

Comment: thats what it does... See the code above. The commit / rollback is not in the code visible as it is not relevant (it crashes inside the loop). In my code it is within Finally lower in the code.

Comment: It is the *first* transaction that is still open.

Comment: yes, but it should be. All inserts within the loop are supposed to be in one transaction. If it fails it would be rolled back in finally. I will edit the code to be more clear

Answer (score 0):

I've found the problem, so posting answer as reference.

we had transaction scope open in our wrapper db class. If i remove the transaction scope definition, it works as advertised.
So bug was on my side, or apparently the transaction scope does not work well with the system.data.sqlite (as it hangs also when i do not try to start another transaction).